# Java: How to create char arrays using Random Class Based on User Input on Length of Array?

Tags: java, arrays, random, char

I have to create a program for school that asks the user how many letter he wants to create, and if he says for example 8, it will create the following:

```
char[] letters = new char[8]
```

It will then assign a random letter to each array indexes (0 to 7) and then the user has to guess the code comprised of 8 letters.

All I know about using random class is this:

```
letterValue = (char) (rand.nextInt(26) + 'a'); // Creates random letters a to z.
```

So how would I assign the 8 random letters to each index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop for the total number of characters that user inputted. 
Each random character you generate needs to be stored at an index in the array.

```
int numberOfCharacters = 8;
char[] letters = new char[numberOfCharacters];
Random random = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCharacters; i++) {
    letters[i] = (char) (random.nextInt(26) + 'a');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful and simple to understand.

Comment: @Majestic Welcome! Can you close out the question by accepting the answer?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow, so new to the features, but here you go. Thanks again!